# changing url structure with htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i have a url

```
http://domain.com/wallpaper-name-of-wallpaper-id.html
```

where `wallpaper-` is prefix of the url and `name-of-wallpaper` is title of the wallpaper while `id` is the actual id of the wallpaper. my current .hataccess file looks like.

```
RewriteRule ^wallpaper-([^/]*)\.html$ wallpaper.php?permalink=$1 [L]
```

but i want to change it to

```
http://domain.com/wallpaper/name-of-wallpaper-id.html
```

so user who will enter the old url will automatically sent to the new url with htaccess.

i have tried. 
`RewriteRule ^wallpaper-([^/]*)\.html$ wallpaper/wallpaper.php?permalink=$1 [R,L]`

but don't seems to work for me. any idea or help?

Comment: Looks like you changed the wrong side. Try replacing the - in the original rule with a /

Comment: @JonStirling do you mean RewriteRule ^(.*)/wallpaper/(.*)$ $1/wallpaper-$2 [R,L]

Comment: How did you take that from my comment? To be honest, I keep reading your question and I'm not actually sure what you're after. Are you after a rule replacement to replace your current rule to work with the new structure, or are you after just the rule to redirect the old URLs to the new ones? Or both / neither?

Comment: @JonStirling i wanted to convert http://asdf.com/prefix-any-string-{id}.html to http://asdf.com/prefix/any-string-{id}.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a new redirect rule before existing rule:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(wallpaper)-([^.]+\.html)$ /$1/$2 [R=302,L,NC]

RewriteRule ^wallpaper/([^.]+)\.html$ wallpaper.php?permalink=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. however this worked for me:


`RewriteRule ^(wallpaper)-([^.]+\.html)$ http://domain.com/$1/$2 [R=302,L,NC]`
`RewriteRule ^wallpaper/([^.]+)\.html$ wallpaper.php?permalink=$1 [L,NC,QSA]`

Comment: Never use a 302, you'll zap all your link juice. Use a 301 instead.

Comment: `302` is for **testing only** the change otherwise browser will cache unwanted URLs. Once tested it can be changed to `301`